# Text and Button Python Tk GUI

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter

How to display the inserted text one by one after pressing a button in Python Tk GUI? I ran the following program successfully but it fills all inserted texts together at the end of the last text. I want to update the text field accordingly by the order of the inserted text. Anyone can help? Thanks.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x400")

def startProgram(shapefile_path):

    t1 = "testing on file 0 successfull\n"
    text.insert('1.0', t1)

    t2 = "testing on file 1 successfull\n" 
    text.insert('1.0', t2)

    t3 = "testing on file2 successfull\n" 
    text.insert('1.0', t3)

text = Text(root, height=8, width=25)
text.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

label = Label(root, text="Status",font=12)
label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


button2=Button(root,text="Start Program", width=20,font=12,command=lambda:     startProgram(0))
button2.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

button3=Button(root, text='Exit Program',    width=20,font=12,command=root.destroy)
button3.grid(row=8, column=0,padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to reverse the order of insertions? If so, than instead of `1.0` you can use `INSERT`:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x400")

message_list = ["testing on file 0 successfull\n",
                "testing on file 1 successfull\n",
                "testing on file2 successfull\n"]

message_list_idx = 0;


def startProgram():
    global message_list_idx

    if message_list_idx >= len(message_list):
        return
    t3 = message_list[message_list_idx]
    text.insert('1.0', t3)
    message_list_idx += 1


text = Text(root, height=8, width=25)
text.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

label = Label(root, text="Status",font=12)
label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


button2=Button(root,text="Start Program", width=20,font=12,
               command=startProgram)

button2.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

button3=Button(root, text='Exit Program',width=20,font=12,
                    command=root.destroy)
button3.grid(row=8, column=0,padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
button2=Button(root,text="Start Program", width=20,font=12,
               command=startProgram)

button2.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

button3=Button(root, text='Exit Program',width=20,font=12,
                    command=root.destroy)
button3.grid(row=8, column=0,padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, actually not reverse the order of insertions, I want to update the text field one by one following the order of text t1, t2, t3. current code display all texts together. Any suggestion?

Comment: So you want to clear the text filed before inserting text, or introduce some delay (e.g. 1s) before new text is shown?

Comment: I want to print any new coming text accordingly in the text field after pressing the button, it is like tracking the procedure of a program.  I tried to clear the previous inserted text and show the new coming but the above code just shows the last text content after pressing the button action, in other words, it only shows the last inserted text rather than display one text after another, even you put time delay between two text.

Comment: @HotPat1000 Sorry, I still dont understand. Maybe you could amend your question to provide more info, some example input, screenshot, etc.

Comment: @ Marcin Thanks for your patient. let me rephrase it, what I really want to do is that when I press the button "Start Program" in the GUI, the function "startProgram" should run and display text one by one, such as display text 1 first, and text 2 second and last is to show text 3. however, the code I wrote above does not do this job, it only displays all the text one time after run over the function "startProgram". So my question is that how I can display the text (t1, t2, t3) one by one in order inside the function. You may get it more clear if u can run the code above. THANKS.

Comment: @HotPat1000 Ok, I think I understand. I edited the answer. Now each button press adds new message to the text box.